# How to link and use embedded framework with Swift and cocoapods?

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods, alamofire

My project include three target: `App`, `Lib`. `Lib` is depended on `Alamofire` via Cocoapod, and have umbrella header named `Lib.h`

Inside a swift source file of `App` target i use

```
import Lib
```

and compiler complain that

> missing required module: 'Alamofire'

My podfile is something like this :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
workspace '../Myworkspace'
xcodeproj 'MyProject'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

link_with 'Lib'

pod 'Alamofire'
```

Comment: Why don't you try to include 'Alamofire' project externally. Well, I have integrated externally and it works fine!